# Activate/deactivate conda environment commands aren't recognized by command prompt

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, conda

I am going crazy over this issue and would really love some help, as I read countless posts on similar issues but I found no solution to my particular problem. I am on **Windows 10** with Anaconda 1.6.2 and Python 2.7.13.

I created a new environment in conda (called AntennaTracking) that I want to activate, while deactivating the default environment called root. When I type "conda info --envs" I get both the environments with a * in front of root, showing that both exist and that root is activated and Antennatracking is not.

**I tried using "activate AntennaTracking" and "deactivate root" in a cmd prompt (and every syntax variation...) and it says that activate/deactivate is not recognized as an internal or external command or an executable file.**

I noticed that the cmd prompt is looking for the command in **C:\Users\Antoine\Anaconda2\Scripts** (which is in the root environment) eventhough the actual script files are not in it, but in **C:\Users\Antoine\Anaconda2\envs\AntennaTracking\Scripts** (so in the new environment).

I found plenty of posts saying that you have to modify the PATH environment variables of the system, which I have tried. I added **C:\Users\Antoine\Anaconda2\envs\AntennaTracking\Scripts** to the PATH, but the cmd prompt still looks for activate/deactivate in **C:\Users\Antoine\Anaconda2\Scripts**.

From what I understand, it doesn't matter where the actual activate/deactivate script is located for it to be used on any environment, as long as the cmd prompt knows to find it. Is that even true?

In any case, I am open for every suggestion you might have and help is greatly appreciated. I have tried too many things to keep track of them all, so shoot.

I am sorry if I am forgetting to include some information in this question. Here are screenshots of the cmd prompt error [cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx4fa.jpg)  and my current PATH  [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8DIY.jpg) (sorry for the French ...)

Thank you!

Comment: Do the files `C:\Users\Antoine\Anaconda2\Scripts\activate.bat` and `C:\Users\Antoine\Anaconda2\Scripts\activate` exist?

Comment: They didn't in this folder, but they existed in C:\Users\Antoine\Anaconda2\envs\AntennaTracking\Scripts.
I tried copying them in C:\Users\Antoine\Anaconda2\Scripts but it gave me an error when trying to use them. 
I missed your comment, but I found the solution and its ridiculously uninteresting: update conda (see my answer). Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.... Found the solution.

I just had to update conda: [cmdprompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCfvX.jpg)