# deactivate in conda 4.3.23 on Windows 64 loose the path

Tags: python, windows, path, conda

I've install conda 4.3.23 on Windows 64 and I have the same problem:

After deactivate an environement, I loose the path and then commands are not recognized as an internal or external command or an executable file.

Please, how can I arrange this problem?

[here you can see the terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOgzz.png)

Another use has the same problem [(his post here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44845026/activate-deactivate-conda-environment-commands-arent-recognized-by-command-prom) and said that conda 4.3.22 arrange this problem, but in 23 it happend again.

Comment: Use full path to `activate`

Answer (score 0):

Your OS cannot find the command activate, you will need to add the PATH to anaconda in the environmental variables.

Windows: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44597801/10213353) to [Conda command is not recognized on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10)